# Latex it is showing the in-text references with numbers, but there is no numbers for references at the end of dcument

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography, biblatex

I have a draft in `elsevier science direct`  LaTeX template. I have chosen the `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}` as bibliography style. There are different styles such as `model1-num-names.bst`, `model5-names.bst`.

The reference numbers in-text is shown correctly, but at the end of document, it is only list of references without numbers. Do you have any tips?

[image: this is the reference example at the end of document]

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal example? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Specifically, see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: @Werner thanks for your comment, the document class is `\documentclass[3p,times,procedia]{elsarticle}`